# Vİsualforce page Currency decimal formating

Tags: visualforce, pdf, formatting, currency

i want to format my currency in visualforce page pdf. Intead of **123,456.78** i want to display **123.456,78**

I mean, integer parts will separate with dot. Decimal parts will separate with comma. I tried to use apex:outputField but when i use the this, decimal part has 5 zero like **36.000,00000**

Can someone help me thank you?

Comment: Could you do the formatting in the controller? Calling .format() on a decimal will format using the user's locale which might be what you want anyway. If it's not, you could cludge the output:

`return d.format().replace(',', 'x').replace('.', ',').replace('x', '.');`

Comment: I can not solve the problem can you help me ? @corpredy problem of the question is correct but now working. I dont want to dummy sobject. How can i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem!

I created a new formula object. the object return type is a number. I avoid currency symbol and i can handle the dot and comma problem.

Link is below. Thank you!

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4HMPSA3